# Can't change to next screen

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova

I am making an app and I have an index. How can I go to my other screen so it can work also?
My other screen is in ingredientes.html but when it changes the screen the process in my other screen doesn't work. But when I open the other screen alone it works. So I don't know what the problem is.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Receta</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/receta.min.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/receta.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" /> 
      <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script> 
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cuenta.js"></script>  

      </head>
      <h1><center>RECETA</h1>
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>

    <button onclick="myFunction('Persona','Recetario')">Bienvenido</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction(name,job)
    {
    alert("Bienvenida " + name + ", puede comenzar a crear su " + job);
    }
    </script>

    </body>

    <form action="/html/tags/html_form_tag_action.cfm" method="get">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Detalles</legend>
    <div>
    <label for="receta">Nombre Receta:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="receta" value="" maxlength="20" /><br>
    </div>
    </fieldset>

    </form>



      </html>

--------------------------------------------------

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
    <title>Ingredient</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/receta.min.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/receta.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/recetas.js">  </script>  
</head><body>
      <h1>INGREDIENTES</h1>
    <ul>

    </ul>
    <select onchange="selectIngredient(this);">
     <option value="Cheese">Cheese</option>
     <option value="Olives">Olives</option>
     <option value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
     <option value="Milk">Milk</option>
    </select>
</body>


      </html>
```

---

```
                             (recetas.js)

function selectIngredient(select)
    { 
      var $ul = $(select).closest('.ui-select').prev('ul');
console.log($ul[0])
  if ($ul.find('input[value=' + $(select).val() + ']').length == 0) {
    console.log('s')
        $ul.append('<li onclick="$(this).remove();">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="' + 
          $(select).val() + '" /> ' +
          $(select).find('option:selected').text() + '</li>');
  }
    }
```

Comment: _" the process in my other screen dont work. "_? Does it crash? Find out why by checking your logcat.

Comment: The point is when i select a ingredient in the list. It should put it in the screen and so on for the other ones. The problem is that when i open it alone it works. And when i open it by a link from the other page it doesnt work.

Comment: So the screen is visible, but the methods won't work? That should also be somewhat debuggable. Sry I have no idea what might be wrong.

Comment: This should not be tagged as android-ndk, it's a phonegap question

Comment: You have `console.log('s')`. Can you see that on logcat?